# On server side sorting, MUI Data Grid re-sort the data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagridview, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I use React Material UI (MUI) DataGrid to view my data.
when I click the sort button, my backend works with the logic "nulls last" so it sends the data as below:

```
0: {countryCode: 91, Name: 'A',createdOn: '2024-01-25'}
1: {countryCode: 92, Name: 'B', createdOn: '2024-01-26'}
2: {countryCode: 93, Name: 'C', createdOn: '2024-01-27'}
3: {countryCode: 90, Name: 'D' createdOn: null}
```

but Data Grid Show the data as below:

```
0: {countryCode: 90, Name: 'D' createdOn: null}
1: {countryCode: 91, Name: 'A',createdOn: '2024-01-25'}
2: {countryCode: 92, Name: 'B', createdOn: '2024-01-26'}
3: {countryCode: 93, Name: 'C', createdOn: '2024-01-27'}
```

I don't want Mui Datagrid to resort my data. I think the server side sorting should do this but it doesn't.
My Mui datagrid Code is below:

[image]